# How do I tile print unusual aspect ratios?

Tags: print-design

If you had only an A4 printer without a tile printing capability, and you needed to create a 47 x 49 cm tiled print of an image, the original aspect ratio of the image, how would you proceed to assemble the image after printing on A4 pages?

Comment: There's [a tutorial on youtube](https://youtu.be/Zfb2PSK8pD0?si=SWJVJQ6jp_kOQlk3)

Comment: You can go to your local print shop and pay 3$ and print this at real size.